# SignInManager PasswordSignInAsync is returning False

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

ASP .Net Core 5.0
Database first EF
Im using Identity (Assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)

I have the following class Im using

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public override string UserName { get; set; } = "";
    public string? Organization { get; set; }
    public override string Email { get; set; } = "";
    public override string PasswordHash { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public override bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public byte[] UserAvatar { get; set; }
    public override string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public override string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public override bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public override int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public override string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public override string? ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public override string? SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public override DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    public override bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public override bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    //public SimpleUser ThisUser { get; set; } = new SimpleUser();
}
```

My startup code here :

```
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<TwisterDBContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

My code from OnPostAsync (which was created using scafolding)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            ApplicationUser thisUser = await GetThisUserById(Input.Email);

            string hashPassword = EncryptPassword.HashPassword(Input.Password, thisUser.SecurityStamp);
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(thisUser, hashPassword, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

Im using email id as username.
Ensured Normalized username and email are set properly in the GetThisUserById function (my custom function to get the record from DB)
I confirmed the hashed password both are matching.
EmailConfirmed is set as true in the DB and coming in as true in the ThisUser record.

Yet, I keep getting Succeeded = false. I definitely sure Im not setting some flag somewhere...

Finally here is the screenshot of the Watch window.
[image: Watch Window]

Comment: `PasswordSignInAsync` should be handling the hashing of the password itself using the default `PasswordHasher<TUser>`. You are pre-hashing the password, which is then getting hashed again so you're getting a login failure. Try passing just "Input.Password".

Comment: Im storing the password after hash+Salting it. Can I specify to the SignInManager to use my hashing function?

Comment: You can by overriding `IPasswordHasher<TUser>` and configuring Identity to use that, however you don't need to. Simply user `PasswordHasher.HashPassword()` to generate a password hash to store. The default implementation uses a 1k iteration Pbkdf2 hash with a random salt which is stored in the returned hash. When you pass the password attempt to `PasswordSignInAsync` it will automatically extract the salt from the stored PW, then re-hash the provided string to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding SigninManager and UserManager is a lot of work. There are so many things that needs to be implemented for it to work.

I tucked my tail and went back to default calls and with the AspNet*** tables in place, I got the data seeded and login works like a charm.